# A standard way of marking alternate tunings for classical guitar?

Tags: sheet-music, classical-guitar, engraving

I'm writing a piece that needs to have a drop D tuning- how do I mark the guitar's tuning at the top of the score? Is there a standard? Something like "E = D" or just "DADGBE"? Maybe a chord fingering chart type thing with the letters at the nut of the guitar?

I'm fine with "Tuning = DADGBE", but if there's a standard, I'm interested in what it is.

Comment: That’s called “scordatura” in the classical world. You might do a web search on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just got some rep with exactly that tuning. It says:

**6 = D**

at the top, but with the 6 inside a circle.

You don’t have to specify the other strings are in standard tuning. Just that the sixth string is D.

Comment: ```6 = Re``` is also pretty common

Comment: It can also show words "muta in" (change to). Like "6ª muta in Ré" etc. etc.

Comment: There is a ⓺ character (DOUBLE CIRCLED DIGIT SIX) but I don't know if that renders correctly in all browsers.

Comment: Is it customary to notate the sounding pitch or just write D as an E in the case of (6) = D? I understand the latter is the case when using an explicit scordatura staff, as seen in Yuxi L's answer.

Comment: @NotLegato Not sure about other strings but they are probably like guitar in that you have to write the sounding pitch. If you want a low D you notate a D on the score. The reason is that most notes can be played in more than one place and the guitarist has to figure out the fingering. If you don’t give them the actual pitches it’s a hopeless task.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I presumed writing transposed pitches would be easier due to habit and muscle memory; a certain arpeggio may naturally fall on the hands as a CV barré. But noted.

Comment: @NotLegato What happens is we develop scordatura muscle memory. We also have to decide where on the neck to play and we have to adjust our analyses for scordatura also. It’s kinda like doubling on banjo or mandolin where we change how the notes on the page translate to our hands.

Answer (score 10):

In *Behind Bars*, Elaine Gould writes that "scordatura"  is indicated as "<string number> to pitch", with <string number> circled (pp. 388–89).

> Indicate the different tunings above the first staff.

See the image below for her example, from Walton's *Five Bagatelles*, No. 3.

[image: Gould p. 389]

Comment: Exactly, see Capricho Arabe by Tarrega for instance.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with all the answers above. An alternate way, in case you ever get crazy tuning schemes, is to notate your alternate tuning with the staff. The advantage with this method is that you don't get confusions over which octaves the alternative tuning notes are in.

An example from Carlo Domeniconi's Koyunbaba:

[image: Koyunbaba first line]

Answer (score 1):

I've seen your last sentence written way more than anything else. It makes immediate sense, and is unequivocal.

Tab may be different, in that the 6 strings would be notated DADGBE on the start of the tab.

Comment: Which sentence are you referring to?

Comment: @JohnKugelman - since my answer is to OP, the OP's last sentence.

Comment: As in, "I'm fine with 'Tuning = DADGBE'..."? Why then add "Tab may be different..."?

Comment: @JohnKugelman - basically, I'm trying to be a little more thorough than necessary?